# Updating child/nested entities in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, automapper

Trying to learn EF here. I have a very basic Parent Child one to many relationship and I am trying to see how I can update the Parent as well as Child entities in one go.

I have tried lots of different things but to avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Parent Class and Dto

```
public partial class Parent
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; } = new List<Child>();
}
```

Child Class and Dto

```
public partial class Child
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }  <-- this is removed in the Child Dto

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Payload

```
{
    "id": "bcf2678e-a318-4cc7-a8d0-1c1d887d4f8c",
    "name": " **New Value here** ",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "1750c5a7-0845-49b8-9cae-064d5a03ef5f",
            "parentId": "bcf2678e-a318-4cc7-a8d0-1c1d887d4f8c",
            "name": " **New Value here** "
        },
        {
            "id": "77ffdbc9-3bc3-4569-9703-4b08187145dc",
            "parentId": "bcf2678e-a318-4cc7-a8d0-1c1d887d4f8c",
            "name": " **New Value here** "
        }
    ]
}
```

Error

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "The association between entity types 'Parent' and 'Child' has been severed, but the relationship is either marked as required or is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable. If the dependent/child entity should be deleted when a required relationship is severed, configure the relationship to use cascade deletes. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the key values.",
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost("SetParent")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ParentDto>> SetParent(ParentDto parentDto)
{
    var parent = await _context.Parents
        .Where(f => f.Id == parentDto.Id)
        .Include(f => f.Children)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    if (parent == null) return NotFound();

    _mapper.Map(parentDto, parent);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    
    return Ok(parentDto);
}
```

Comment: Research AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: Look at [Attaching a serialized graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/identity-resolution#attaching-a-serialized-graph)

Comment: Since what you are trying to do is a disconnected graph update, I don't think the mapper will not resolve all the possible changes in your Graph, code will be different depending on the scenario, this page illustrates better what you are trying to accomplish: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-disconnected-entity-graph-ef-core.aspx

Comment: Also, since the childs in your payload already belong to a parent, you can remove the parentId attribute from them.

Comment: I try your code but it works well in my project, i can't reproduce this issue, Have you tried to follow the error message to add cascade deletes in your configuration?

Comment: @XinranShen looks like that was it. After I changed the DeleteBehavior to Cascade from ClientSetNull, it works flawlessly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @XinranShen, the way to fix this issue is to change the OnDelete behavior to Cascade like the Error is saying.

So changed the DeleteBehavior from

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Child", "Tools");
            entity.HasOne(d => d.Parent).WithMany(p => p.Children)
                 .HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentId)
                 .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
        });
```

to

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Child", "Tools");
            entity.HasOne(d => d.Parent).WithMany(p => p.Children)
                 .HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentId)
                 .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        });
```